# I'm posting my a string to my backend but the backend returns a status code 500: View function did not return a response

Tags: javascript, python, post, python-requests

I'm trying to send a string from my front-end to my back-end when a delete button gets clicked, but my back-end returns status code 500: View function did not return a response

I've tried using request.get_data, request.get_json, i've tried just sending a string from the front-end and sending an array

javascript

```
const ip = '192.168.0.116';
const backend_IP = `http://${ip}:5000`;
const backend = backend_IP + '/api/v1';

const listenToTrashes = function() {
  document
    .querySelector('.js-table')
    .addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      const delButton = event.target.closest('.js-listendelete');
      if (delButton && this.contains(delButton)) {
        const firstCell = delButton.closest('tr').querySelector('td');
        if (firstCell) {
          console.log(firstCell.innerHTML);
          const data = firstCell.innerHTML;
          const body = `{"htmlvalue" : "${data}"}`;
          handleData(backend + '/table', next, 'POST', body);
        }
      }
    });
};
```

DataHandler

```
const handleData = function(url, callback, method = 'GET', body = null) {
  fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    body: body,
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
  })
    .then(function(response) {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(`Probleem bij de fetch(). Status Code: ${response.status}`);
      } else {
        console.info('Er is een response teruggekomen van de server');
        return response.json();
      }
    })
    .then(function(jsonObject) {
      console.info('json object is aangemaakt');
      console.info('verwerken data');
      callback(jsonObject);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error(`fout bij verwerken json ${error}`);
    });
};
```

back-end

```
@app.route(endpoint + "/table", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def db_to_table():
    if request.method == "GET":
        antw_db = conn.get_data("SELECT f.products_barcode, f.date, f.expirationDate, f.amount, p.name FROM fridge_has_products AS f left join products AS p ON f.products_barcode = p.barcode ORDER BY f.date DESC")
        json_db = jsonify(antw_db)
        return json_db
    elif request.method == "POST":
        title = request.get_json()
        print(title)
```

I just need the value from the front-end to be printed in the back-end for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the back-end, there is no return value for POST request.
Try to return some string.
e.g., `return 'test'`, `return jsonify(title)`, etc.